# How to bind variable in .js-meta.xml file of LWC component?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, xml, bind-variable

Javascript :

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';

export default class ApcApiArticle extends LightningElement {

@api prevPart;

connectedCallback() {
    this.sfdcBaseURL = window.location.origin;
    let org = this.sfdcBaseURL;
    this.prevPart = org;
}
```

HTML :

```
         <template>
            <a href={prevPart}> Link to >
            </a>
         </template>
```

.js-meta.XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
<apiVersion>57.0</apiVersion>
<isExposed>true</isExposed>
 <targets>
<target>lightningCommunity__Default</target>
<target>lightningCommunity__Page</target>
 </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
<targetConfig targets="lightningCommunity__Default">
  <property
    name="prevPart"
    label="URL Article "
    type="String" 
    **default="prevPart"**
  />
```

i expose this component in community site , i want the default link to take the url but it doesn't work - Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

The name of the property used in the meta file should be same as the public property created in the javascript file.

Javascript :

```js
@api santePart;
```

.js-meta.XML :

```html
<property
    name="santePart"
    label="URL Article"
    type="String" 
    default="https://salesforce.stackexchange.com"
  />
```

Comment: Yes it's , i copied the wrong variable .  i want the default value to be dynamic ..

Comment: Try by removing the component from the community site, then publishing the site, again re-adding the component and re-publishing the site.

Comment: it doesn't worked .. it treats the variable as string

Comment: even with **default = {!prevPart}** doesn't worked , i think it's impossible ..